# Dapper - multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dapper

For the code shown below, I am getting the following error message.

*** Error ***

> When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if
> you have keys other than Id (Parameter 'splitOn')

From what i understand i am passing the splitOn parameter am i missing something obvious?

**Code**

```
 using (var connection = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    LookupTables = connection.Query<LookupTable, List<LookupValue>, LookupTable>("exec [lookups].[SelAllLookupTable]", 
                        (lookuptable, lookupvalue) => {
                            lookuptable.LookUpValues = lookupvalue.ToList<LookupValue>(); 
                            return lookuptable;
                        }, splitOn: "LookupValueID").ToList();
                }
```

Update

Stored Proc Code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [lookups].[SelAllLookupTable]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT lt.[LookupTableID],
        lt.[GUID],
        lt.[CreatedBy],
        lt.[CreatedOn],
        lt.[UpdatedBy],
        lt.[UpdatedOn],
        lt.[ChangeReason],
        lt.[Name],
        lt.[Description],
        lv.[LookupValueID],
        lv.[LookupTableID],
        lv.[GUID],
        lv.[CreatedBy],
        lv.[CreatedOn],
        lv.[UpdatedBy],
        lv.[UpdatedOn],
        lv.[ChangeReason],
        lv.[Description],
        lv.[DisplayOrderNo]
    FROM lookups.LookupTable lt
    LEFT JOIN lookups.LookupValue lv ON lt.LookupTableID = lv.LookupTableID
END
```

Comment: Could you add the SQL code of the stored procedure?

Comment: @Steve I have added the stored proc code in thank you

Comment: I would try to add the field names instead of * and you need only the ID for the joined table in the splitOn parameter _LookupTableID_

Comment: Thanks that moved the code on a bit and i am now getting results although i was expecting 1 lookuptable with a list containing 2 lookupvalues but i am 2 lookuptables with no values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your  data, but I think you should change your code in this way

```
// Where we store the distinct LookUpTable found by the query
Dictionary<int, LookUpTable> result = new Dictionary<int, LookUpTable>();

using (var connection = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var LookupTables = connection.Query<LookupTable, LookUpValue, LookupTable>("exec [lookups].[SelAllLookupTable]",
        (lkt, lkv) =>
        {
            // Check if we have the instance already in the dictionary
            // add it if not, 
            if (!result.ContainsKey(lkt.LookUpTableID))
               result.Add(lkt.LookUpTableID, lkt);
            result[lkt.LookupTableID].LookUpValues.Add(lkv);
            return lkt;
        }, splitOn: "LookupValueID").ToList();
}
return result.Values.ToList();
```

Dapper will not build and pass a list of LookUpValue directly, but it will iterate over the records creating the objects from each returned record and passing these objects one by one to the lambda expression.
Your lambda expression could use a Dictionary to store each LookupTable object received and add the LookupValue object to its property. When Dapper ends its iteration over the record your objects are stored in the Values collection of the dictionary

Of course this assumes that your class LookUpTable has a `List<LookUpValue>` property

```
public class LookupTable
{
    public int LookupValueID { get; set; }
    .... other properties ....
    public List<LookUpValue> LookUpValues {get;set} = new List<LookUpValue>();
}
```

Notice how the property creates the list at initialization to avoid complex logic in the Dapper lambda expression.

Comment: The code is running now and is giving data back however for the result i was expecting one lookuptable with a list containing 2 lookupvalues however i am getting 2 lookuptables with 1 lookupvalue in each

Comment: I see, I have now understood better your case and changed the example. It is a common scenario with dapper that could be resolved with the help of a dictionary variable

Comment: Ahh great thank you, you are the best! that works as i wanted :)

Comment: Rechecked this code and there was an error. In the dictionary one should add a ref to the LookupTable not to the LookupValue (one doesn't appreciate Intellisense enough until you write code like this by hand)